# Tedious sql query returning empty object (can´t return custom array and callback not working)

Tags: node.js, tedious, tediousjs

Im using Tedious in Node JS to return a simple SQL Query :

```
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;  
var config = {  
    server: 'myserver.database.windows.net',
    authentication: {
        type: 'default',
        options: {
            userName: 'myusername',
            password: 'mypassword',
            rowCollectionOnDone: true,
            rowCollectionOnRequestCompletion: true
        }
    },
    options: {
        encrypt: true,
        database: 'mydatabase'
    }
};  
const connection = new Connection(config);  
connection.on('connect', function(err) { 
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        console.log("Connected");  
    }
});  

var Request = require('tedious').Request  
var TYPES = require('tedious').TYPES;  
let results = [];

function checkId(cid) {  
    request = new Request("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = @cid",function(err, rowCount, rows) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });  
    
    request.addParameter('cid', TYPES.NVarChar, cid);  
    request.on('row', function(row) {
        results.push(row);
    });
    console.log(results) // I can see results array perfectly here
    connection.execSql(request); 
    //return callback(null, results); // Tried setting callback as parameter too in this function but got error "callback is not a function"
}
```

When I call the statement function outside like this:

```
var sqlquery = new checkId(passid);
console.log(sqlquery);
```

I get:

```
"sqlquery {}"
```

I other words, an **[object Object]** but empty (obviously, JSON.strinfigy in empty it's useless). I already tried to use callback as a workaround as commented in the code above but got error, how can I see results array when I call the function ?

Answer (score 1):

Knowing that Tedious it's async and results won´t process on time to get them outside (reason why it´s empty object) and since there´s no specific answer to this anywhere (a lot of theory yes, but not a clear explanation due that some code it´s outdated like curiosly where you use callback as a set function, there´s no guidance of how to mix promises with Tedious properly, answers only show results in console.log or  some people may be beginners with the sync/async concept), I post here a commented way that worked for me in case anyone may need it:

```
///Connection
    var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;  
    var config = {  
        server: 'myserver.database.windows.net',
        authentication: {
            type: 'default',
            options: {
                userName: 'myusername',
                password: 'mypassword',
                rowCollectionOnDone: true,
                rowCollectionOnRequestCompletion: true
            }
        },
        options: {
            encrypt: true,
            database: 'mydatabase'
        }
    };  
    const connection = new Connection(config);  
    connection.on('connect', function(err) { 
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            console.log("Connected");  
        }
    });  
    var Request = require('tedious').Request  
    var TYPES = require('tedious').TYPES;
```

Now , inside an **async** function you can call this example query with params (must be inside async function in order to use **'return await'** and that everything syncs to avoid empty data :

```
    async your_function(){
                var id = 'id you want or user inputs';
                const allData = [];
                // We now set the promise awaiting it gets results
                await new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
                    const request = new Request("SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = @id", function(err, rowCount) {
                         if (err) {
                             return reject(err);
                         } else {
                             console.log(rowCount + ' rows');
                         }
                     });
                     
                     request.addParameter('id', TYPES.NVarChar, id); //Param id declaration
                     request.on('row', function(columns) {
                         columns.forEach(function(column) {
                             allData.push(column.value); //Push the result to array
                         });
                     });
             
                     request.on('doneProc', function (rowCount, more, returnStatus, rows) {
                         console.log('onDoneProc');
                         return resolve(allData); //Here we resolve allData using promise in order to get it´s content later
                     });
             
                     connection.execSql(request);
             
                 });

                 var mydata = allData;  // Now You can assign it or use the same object as well
    }
```

Hope it helps someone as it did to me.